# Components section empty in Xcode 7 B5

Tags: ios, xcode

I've got this issue on two of my Macs.

[image]

On the one machine I deleted Xcode 7 beta 4 and downloaded the beta 5 version and installed. Same issue.

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?
I need iOS7 /8 simulators on these machines.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help, because I used this for something else. But if you go into finder and locate the file "iPhoneSimulator.platform" from a different version of xcode (like xcode 6.4) you could copy it over to the equivalent location in beta 5 folder. I've only done something like this for a different reason, but if you desperate you could do this.

```
Applications > Xcode 6.4 > Show Package Contents > Contents > Developer > Platforms > iPhoneSimulator.platform
```

Comment: Sort of helps. Allows me to use older versions of iOS8 but not the new ones obviously. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Definitely! At least you have something to work with